# Are weapons (or the iron sword specifically) consumed by embarking with them in A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

Whenever I take a freshly-forged iron sword with me on my adventures down the dusty path, it's gone when I return.

I'm not getting any messages that it's breaking, etc, and I'm using it throughout that journey, but when I get back, it tells me I have no iron swords, and have to make a new one for each journey.

At first I thought this might be a death penalty, since I frequently go as far as my food/water will let me, with no plan for how to return, but I tried getting back safely (rather than waking up there reincarnated) and it didn't help.

Note:  I'm pretty early on, and I gather this game has some twists, so please try to avoid any *major* plot spoilers if they're not crucial.

Comment: It's been a while since I've played this, but as I recall, you only lose weapons if you die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, **weapons should only be lost if you die on your trip,** as will all other items you had with you, except for armor, water and storage.

One possible area for confusion:

**You have two inventories.**  When you're in camp, there are two independent lists of items - one is "supplies" and the other is what you see on the "a dusty road" screen.  So, if you have items "equipped" on the road screen, they'll show as "0" in supplies.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Can I retrieve the items I lost when I died? are they left somewhere on the map?